# Webcam interfacing using Javacv or lti-civil library. which one is better in terms of performance and better interfacing..?

Tags: java, webcam, javacv

I want to only ask that which library will give **better performance** among LTI-Civil and JavaCV for webcam interfacing ,For Image Capturing and all that purpose.
How well both the library do live streaming in robust way,I mean without any kind of bug.Like Memory leakage and all that.
Give appropriate justification for that please.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using LTI-Civil for years now. I haven't had performance issues with it, but:

- for Windows the distributed binary lacks 64-bit support, and it's too difficult to build for me
- it has threading problems in the C code with multiple cameras, fixed that (for Linux only).

JavaCV I have no experience with, maybe I should try that.

Bram

Comment: You can also look at jLibuvc, which is newer, and promising. I tried it a few months ago and it seems to work at least.